# how to load a .xib file consisting a tabbar controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a .xib file which consist of a tabbar controller, i want to load it using navigation controller in my didselect row. My parent view is a tabbar controller.How to hide my current tabbar controller and display the new.

Comment: Please provide some of your code.....

Comment: Make two tabBar and just use addsubView and removeFromSuperview..

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a [custom single tab-bar controller](https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController) in your app.  When a user clicks on cell of UItableView a tab that leads to a new set of tabs, replace all of the tabs in the single-tab-bar controller.

Now user navigates back then change it to old tabs to tab-bar controller.

I think it is not best UI. but according to your requirement it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide Programmatically your UITabBar controller by using below code :

```
AppDelegateFileName *appDelegate = (AppDelegateFileName *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.tabbarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: I am using this code to show tab bar controller during app lunch but it is not working on did select                           '[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TabbarController" owner:self options:nil];
    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.rootController];'